# MobilePush SDK 8.0.1 crash

Tags: marketing-cloud, android, mobilepush-android

Using `com.salesforce.marketingcloud:marketingcloudsdk:8.0.1` leads to crash on users devices with

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
salesforceKeyGenerator.getEncryptionKey(moduleApplicationId) must not be null
com.salesforce.marketingcloud.sfmcsdk.components.encryption.EncryptionManager.<init> (EncryptionManager.java:16)
com.salesforce.marketingcloud.sfmcsdk.SFMCSdkComponents.<init> (SFMCSdkComponents.java:48)
com.salesforce.marketingcloud.sfmcsdk.SFMCSdk$Companion.configure$lambda-14$lambda-13 (SFMCSdk.java:128)
com.salesforce.marketingcloud.sfmcsdk.SFMCSdk$Companion.$r8$lambda$LwdV5u_X536Smz_5rvQah3BxL4s (SFMCSdk.java)
androidx.room.QueryInterceptorDatabase$$InternalSyntheticLambda$0$f0a2e0dee2bf74e5faa6c90a6215e00ddf8c35f1b05ac8264a72af5cdd6d7162$0.run$bridge (QueryInterceptorDatabase.java:2)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:923)
```

It looks like SDK uses `SHA1PRNG` at `SalesforceKeyGenerator.generateUniqueId` which it shouldn't according to documentation: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/security-crypto-provider-deprecated-in.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Using SDK leads to crashes. I have added a stack trace that points to the specific line of code inside the salesforce SDK. 

I'm asking for help on how to contact the SDK developer to let them know that the latest release of the Android SDK has issues.

Comment: Thank you.  Are there any specific devices and/or Android versions that are affected in your experience @Sergii?

Comment: Also, would you mind sharing the frequency with which you're seeing this crash?

Comment: 682 crash events affecting 21 users, Android 10 - 72%, Android 11 - 23%, Android 9 - 1%, Xiaomi Mi A2 Lite - 30%, Samsung Galaxy A10 - 39%, Galaxy A51 - 23%.


But we stopped after a very small rollout

Comment: Thank you.  Researching.

Comment: I've noticed that crashes happen 100% of the time in the background according to Crashlytics. Could it be that SDK tries to initialize itself before the configuration block is called?  Dunno

Comment: @BillMote does the 8.0.2 version include the fix for this crash?

Comment: Yes it does Sergii.

Answer (score 0):

Please update to version 8.0.2 of the Android SDK.